# ¿Cómo instalar la extensión "IMAP PHP" en AWS EC2?

Tags: php, php7, aws, ec2

Estoy usando una instancia de AWS EC2, específicamente, "PHP 8.1 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.0.3".

La versión de PHP que estoy usando es: 8.1.23

- He creado un fichero dentro de etc/php.d/: `sudo vi /etc/php.d/30-imap.ini`
- Le he añadido `extension=imap` dentro del fichero creado
- He intentado instalar la extensión: `yum install php81-imap`

Error recibido: `Error: Unable to find a match: php81-imap`

¿Cómo puedo instalar esto?

Comment: Seguramente necesitas agregar un repo, muy recomendable *EPEL*: `yum install epel-release php-imap` .

Comment: @Sal el problema es que "amazon-linux-extras" no existe en AL2023. Encontré soluciones para AL2 pero no para AL2023

Comment: Resultado de tu línea: yum install epel-release php-imap
Last metadata expiration check: 17:09:10 ago on Thu 23 Nov 2023 05:40:46 PM UTC.
No match for argument: epel-release
No match for argument: php-imap
Error: Unable to find a match: epel-release php-imap

Comment: Una lástima; entonces ¿cómo instalaste PHP8? si compilaste intenta [re-compilar con IMAP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/imap.installation.php).